# .htaccess - Dynamic URL redirecting

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to dynamically redirect URLs. I tried a lot of .htaccess combinations, but none of them worked for me.

This is my dynamic URL: http://localhost/verload.php?name=example

This is the URL I want: http://localhost/example

And I need to exclude directories "loader" and "admin" which I want to be reachable only by http://admin.localhost/.

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks

EDIT: I don't want the URL to change. I just want http://localhost/example to point on http://localhost/verload.php?name=example. I hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/loader/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/admin/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /verload.php?name=$1 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. But I do not want the URL to change. I just want http://localhost/example to point to http://localhost/verload.php?name=example. I'm sorry I didn't write it clearly. And exception for admin and loader does not work.